# Find the supremum and infimum of $A = \left \{ \frac{(-1)^{n}n}{(-1)^{n + 1} n + 1}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right \}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$A = \left \{  \frac{(-1)^{n}n}{(-1)^{n + 1} n + 1}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right \}$$

So the supremum is $\frac{-1}{2}$, and the infimum would be $-1$, right? However the solutions say that the infimum = minimum $= -2$. Where did the $-2$ come from? I don't see how the sequence contains $-2$

Comment: The sets in your first and second lines appear to be different. Note that $(-1)^{n+1}n+1 \ne (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)$.

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(-1)^{n+1}n+1 \ne (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)$. So in fact
$$A = \left\{ \frac{-1}{2}, \frac{2}{-1}, \frac{-3}{4}, \frac{4}{-3}, \frac{-5}{6}, \frac{6}{-5}, \cdots \right\}$$
Hopefully now you can work out why $-2$ is an element of $A$, and why it's the infimum.